# Opencart does one extra redirect to index.php?_route_ before going back to SEO URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Thanks for the awesome forum. I love it.
I looked for an answer to my question, but i haven't been lucky.

My website: http://zeroohm.com/arduino

If you look at the redirect test:

[Redirection details in an easy to understand image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hm0a.png)

You can see, there is a redirect to [https://www.zeroohm.com/index.php?*route*=arduino/](https://www.zeroohm.com/index.php?_route_=arduino/)

and I just cant figure out how to get rid of it. Everytime time I try to edit my `.htaccess` file, it never works.
Here is my htaccess file.

```
    RewriteEngine on

#force trainling slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
#end of force trailing slash

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zeroohm\.ae$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.zeroohm\.ae$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.zeroohm\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

#ip concaloizaation 
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 192\.163\.199\.45
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html$
#RewriteRule .* /index.html[R=301,L]

RewriteOptions inherit

# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 
# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.
# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymlinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
#we need to remove this re-write rule so tht we avoid 1 re-redrection.
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]



#libwww-perl security fix
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

# check if url has www or not, add www if not available. if avaiable dont do anything.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ https%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#end

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?_route_=?([^&\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# force incoming traffic coming from HTTP to Https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#end

# cache to keep it at client pc
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
    Expiresactive on
    # set default
    Expiresdefault "access plus 24 hours"
    Expiresbytype image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
    Expiresbytype image/gif "access plus 1 months"
    Expiresbytype image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
    Expiresbytype image/png "access plus 1 months"
    Expiresbytype text/css "access plus 1 months"
    Expiresbytype text/javascript "access plus 1 months"
    Expiresbytype application/javascript "access plus 1 months"
    Expiresbytype application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 months"
</ifmodule>

#gzip compression
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Any suggestions would be so appreciated on 
1. how to get rid of the extra redirect (intdex.php?*route*)
2. any other improvements on the htaccess file

Thanks all.

Comment: It’s most likely your non-www-to-www redirect. Stuff like this you should always try and handle first, before all the other rules that are supposed to rewrite internally only.

Comment: THANK YOU. I can't tell you how thankful I am.

Comment: if you have any other recommendations on how to have 1 simple redirect. so the following URL would be re-written such as zeroohm.com/arduino -------> https://www.zeroohm.com/arduino/

Comment: hey,, i fixed it. i just added a " / ". as shown here:    RewriteRule ^ https%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} / [R=301,L]